# How to get current network signal strength in android?

Tags: android, gsm, signal-strength, network-connection

I need to know the currently available network (mobile data plan) signal strength in android for <2.3 devices ? I have used SignalStrength but that is even giving signal strength when mobile is in airplan mode also(seems dat is radio signal strength) not current data plan signal strength, please help me: (

Comment: Did you check [this](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/)?

Comment: Here is an example for Android 2.1 (API Level 7) using a PhoneStateListener and a onSignalStrengthsChanged-Event -> [Get Signal Strength](http://www.stevenmarkford.com/android-get-signal-strength/)

Comment: thanks for ur reply soon. but i could not find clear solution there @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: @tolga, if we remove sim/put mobile in Airplane mode also that approach is giving signal strength as like a inbuilt  "About phone" feature... i just want the current (CDMA/GSM) data plan signal strength

Comment: Do you get a signal strength when you reboot your phone? Maybe the signal strength doesn't get reset automatically.

Comment: Yes , its coming.. @tolga

Comment: @apexer I tested the example which I posted above on my phone (HTC Desire C). When I switch it to airplane mode, it still reads a value but this value does not change (I guess its the last measured value before switching). After I reboot my phone (still in airplane mode), the example reads the value 99 which means "not known" or "not detectable". According to the [SignalStrength Class Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) valid values are 0-31 and 99. In a case like this, check if your phone is in airplane mode and act accordingly.

Comment: many thanks @tolga... I have considered ur point.. let me check twmr in all other cdma/gsm devices.